# Controller#needs - Route has dot in it?

Tags: ember.js

I recently had to convert all of my routes to the deeply nested version. For example: `pages.page` became `books.book.pages.page`. It was necessary for some of the linking I was doing. The problem is that I have a controller that declares that it needs another controller. Specifically, it needed the `book` controller. But now the `book` controller is the `books.book` controller. This presents an issue because this code no longer works:

```
this.get('controllers.books.book');
```

Now it thinks that `book` is just a property of the `books` controller, when in reality, it's all one property. How can I resolve this issue? So far I've tried these methods, none of which work:

```
this.get('controllers').get('books.book');
this.get('controllers.`books.book`');
this.get("controllers.'books.book'");
```

EDIT: I should also point out that calling `this.get('controllers').needs` gives me the array: `['application', 'books.book']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.get('controllers.booksBook')` will work.

Because Ember uses a few different naming conventions in various places, whenever an object is registered with the application container its name is normalized. This ensures different lookup formats always resolve the same way. As a consequence you can use a different lookup format to unambiguously reference controllers in property paths.

The normalization converts dotted-path and underscored strings to camelized. Forward-slashes are preserved. You can take a look at the tests in `packages/ember-application/tests/system/dependency_injection/normalization_test.js` for more detail.

Comment: That actually didn't seems to work. Using `controllerFor` returns the correct controllers, but using that code just returns undefined. Also, I added a tiny bit of info to the first post to clarify something.

Comment: Scratch that, this actually did work. I just have to declare that the controller needs `booksBook` and not `books.book`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting to the PagesController simply by using `this.get('controllers.pages');`? I believe you don't have to specify the whole path.

Here's a short example that worked for me:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('books', function() {
    this.resource('book', function() {
      this.resource('pages', function() {
        this.route('page', function() {

        });
      });
    });
  });
});

App.PagesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.BookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "pages",
  pages: function() {
    return 'My PagesController, ' + this.get('controllers.pages')
  }.property()
});
```

Comment: In your case, `pages` is the real name of the route. In your code, instead of `book`, use `books.book`, and then `books.book.pages`, etc.  (As shown here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) You'll find then that your code doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you're telling me, but if you have controllers named BooksBookPagesPageController due to your deep nesting. That just seems convoluted. So this could be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Trust me, it's a MUCH cleaner approach. But I ran into problems while linking. Specifically, I had some corner cases where I couldn't link to the deeper routes because I wasn't able to provide all of the models needed. This way is more verbose, but it's more explicit and a bit easier.